# Limit proofs by definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> a.) Show that $\lim(1/\sqrt{n})=0$ by using the definition.
>
> b.) Let $d\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $d>1$. USe Bernoulli's Inequality to
>   show that the sequence $d^n$ is not bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, hence it
>   is not convergent.
>
> c.) Let $b\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $0<b<1$, show that $\lim(nb^n)=0$ by
>   using the Binomial Theroem.

My attempt:

a.) Given an $\epsilon$, I need to find an $N$ that satisifies the condition of convergence. Thus I have to bound $|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-0|<\epsilon$; which essentially means, when is $|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|<\epsilon$, correct? So, given $\epsilon>0$ we have $|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|<\epsilon$ which implies that $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$, correct? Thus $\forall$ $n>N$ then $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$, hence $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon$, so we have $|x_n-x|=|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-0|=|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|<\epsilon$. Q.E.D.

Comment: $N$ should be integer so choose $N=\lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\rfloor+1$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane what are those brackets you have outside the fraction? And why would adding by one make $N$ an interger?

Comment: @Q.matin it's the floor function, the next smaller integer to a given number.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for clarifying, Stefan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part c,
since $0 < b < 1$,
let $b = 1/(1+c)$
where $c > 0$.
This is an example of the slogan
"always expand around $0$."

Then $n b^n = n/(1+c)^n$.

Showing $n b^n \to 0$
is the same as showing
$(1+c)^n/n \to \infty$.

Using the binomial theorem,
we can show much more,
namely that
$(1+c)^n/n^r \to \infty$
for any positive real $r$.

To show this,
let $m = \lceil r+2 \rceil$,
and $n$ any integer
greater than $m^2$.

By the binomial theorem,
$(1+c)^n
= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}c^k
>\binom{n}{m}c^m
> (n-m+1)^m \dfrac{c^m}{m!}
= n^m(1-(m-1)/n)^m \dfrac{c^m}{m!}
$.
Since $n > m^2$,
$(m-1)/n < 1/m$
so
$(1-(m-1)/n)^m
> (1-1/m)^m > 1/e$.

Therefore
$(1+c)^n
> n^m\dfrac{c^m}{e m!}
> n^{r+1}\dfrac{c^m}{e m!}
$,
or
$(1+c)^n/n^r
> n \dfrac{c^m}{e m!}
$.
Since $c$ and $r$ are fixed,
and $m$ is also,
$\dfrac{c^m}{e m!}$ is fixed
(once $c$ and $r$ are chosen),
so $(1+c)^n/n^r \to \infty$
as $n \to \infty$.